# vimrc to detect remote connection

Tags: regex, vim, ssh, remote-access

At the moment I have to hard code the names of servers on my vimrc in order to either make it different on the remote machine. This is done by conditional statement using `hostname()` function in vim. I want to make the conditional to be based on the status of remote connection and not on the hostname. So...

The first possible solution I found was using the following bash command in `system()`:

```
cat /proc/$PPID/status | head -1 | cut -f2
```

This does not work because I use GNU `screen` and this will not detect my connection status properly.

The second possible solution I am exploring right now is using `who am i` This reliably shows whether or not remote connection has been made from which client, but I have trouble getting it working with `system()`

```
if substitute(system('who am i'), "theclient", ????, "") == ""
     ...
```

How could I get `????` to extract my client name somehow??

Even if the second solution works, allowing me to use .vimrc for many different remote machines, it is still tied to one client. I want the conditional to work in all remote session, regardless of the client name. So I am wondering, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line allows me to create a variable that detects the remote connection status:

```
let g:remoteSession = ($STY == "")
```

Now you can surround the lines that you want to be ignored in the remote connection via:

```
if g:remoteSession
    ...
endif
```

On a side note, I do not know how expensive it is look up the environment variable compared to the global variable, but I am guessing the difference is negligible. The system call in an environment like cygwin where `fork()` is inefficient, it is worth doing the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding conditional logic to a shared `~/.vimrc`, you could alternatively source system-local settings. I use the following:

```
" Source system-specific .vimrc first.
if filereadable(expand('~/local/.vimrc'))
    source ~/local/.vimrc
endif
" Stop sourcing if inclusion guard exists.
if exists('g:loaded_vimrc')
    finish
endif

" Common settings of .vimrc here...
```

I find this more scalable than trying to maintain an ever-changing list of hostnames in a central location.

Comment: I wonder if I should place the common settings above the conditionals. I think .vimrc is read sequentially and the later scripts have a higher precedence. Am I right? I am not certain, but I think things will get complicated when there I am running plugins like `vundle` or other functions that needs to be tweaked inline. I could potentially have the duplicates in the system-specific .vimrc, but I think embedding and merging scripts reduces the time to debug. I do not have specific settings for different machines, just one for local .vimrc and remote .vimrc, to reduce the latency.